# How to generate a searchable AND dependent dropdown list (input from one sheet, "base data" is in another)?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, dropdown, searchable

For my project, in order to improve user-friendliness, I decide to switch from just dependent dropdown list to dependent AND searchable dropdown list.

The first cell (call it A1) is where the plastic group is input (Plastic group is TPU, PA, Nylon...), the second cell is a dropbox, where I'll type a part of the material name inside and it will show me the suggestions. The typed material name in the second box is dependent on the first one. For example, if I have "TPU" in the first cell and "660" in the second, only TPU materials with "660" as part of their names will appear in the suggestion drop-down list.

I'm able to make "just dependent" and "just searchable", but is there anyway to combine these two together?

Thanks for your help.

I have tried the dependent route, using INDIRECT function and naming the sub-list of specific material names by their group. Currently, I'm "going around" by combining them all together in a single list (Material name) - they are not sorted by group and that is not what I want.

Comment: You will have only 2 cells with dependent and searchable list or more? The second question is: you used tag "VBA" here, but you're trying to do this with pure Excel? It is possible without VBA, except deleting second cell (material) after refreshing first list with material group, what can be annoying to user.

Comment: @RafałB. I have 4 cells in total, in which cell #2 is dependent on cell #1, and cell #4 is dependent on cell #3. These 2 groups are independent from each other - that is why I only mention 2 cells.

My main issue is to combine dependent dropdown and searchable together. For the sub-level cell (cell #2 and #4), there are over 30 entries for each entry of cell #1 and #3. And the "mother" cell only has 4~6 entries each.

Thanks for your comment, I've fixed my tags.